# How to fix 'error reading setup initialization file' when installing activeX in IE?

Tags: c#, activex

In Windows 10 Educational Edition, 64-bit system, I tried to run an activeX in Internet Explorer 11 (version 11.765.17134.0) with **firewall closed**. But after I clicked [install] button on the pop-up window, an '**Error reading setup initialization file**' error message displayed.

According to [2237-error-setup-initialization](https://www.landfx.com/kb/installation-help/plugins-errors/item/2237-error-setup-initialization.html), I closed firewall and antivirus programs, but it didn't work.

The web page **index.html** which I opened contains:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function load() {
            var dom = document.getElementById("activex");
            dom.regJs(window, 'test');
        }

        function test() {
            alert("register callback function");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="load()">
<object id="activex" classid="clsid:D2BBB592-B43D-47EA-BF72-C986862F8350" codebase="setup.exe" width="100%" height="200"></object>
</body>
```

Comment: google for "msi installation log" and find your actual error

Comment: Already set by [how-to-enable-windows-installer-logging](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/223300/how-to-enable-windows-installer-logging), didn't see any log when opening index.html.

Comment: The msi log will be generated in ```%temp%``` directory only when I click the setup.exe to install the program.